Problem with Vimeo videos (net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 206 (Partial Content)) on Webflow site
URL: https://www.studiocantina.com/
On my website I'm having intermittent errors with Vimeo videos.
The site is built and hosted with Webflow, and all videos are HTML coded in, pulling from Vimeo's Video File Links for each video.
The problem is intermittent on the site, and can often be solved with a page refresh, however that's not ideal for a client facing website!
It seems to be the case that if one video on a page doesn't load, they all don't load – it's not localised to one or two video per page, with the rest still loading.
I haven't checked in rigorously, but it appears to be a Chrome only issue. Safari seems fine.
Looking at the console errors on Chrome, I get some variation of this for each one:
GET https://download-video.akamaized.net/v3-1/playback/803ea207-6d0f-4024-9b00-f16973d60143/50349501-e1659e54?__token__=st=1721818448~exp=1721832848~acl=%2Fv3-1%2Fplayback%2F803ea207-6d0f-4024-9b00-f16973d60143%2F50349501-e1659e54%2A~hmac=ce412b54a5ac3142283edd047e0322ec8c80855a356ced003bd8776188fe2591&r=dXMtZWFzdDE%3D net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 206 (Partial Content)
Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be hugely appreciated!
Many thanks
James
I was expecting the videos to run normally each time, and there to not be this intermittent problem.
